# Adding property to already created object but with name as variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if you can assign a brand new property to an already initialized object in JavaScript, but using a variable as the property name.

```
var obj = {};

var newPropertyName = 'Test';

//I know you can do the following:
obj.newProperty = something;

//i also understand you can then use string to get the value:
obj["newProperty"] = something;

//but can i do this:
obj[newPropertyName] = something  //so it can then be retrieved by using 

//that way it could then be used like this.
obj.Test
```

#### EDIT:

The example above is what I will be using, but I am building a SQL syntax capable query library for entities.

Comment: Have you run your code? You can easily see if this is possible

Comment: It does not work, so i am asking it to see if there is a way to use a variable as a new property name. Was using this just as a example to explain what i was trying to find out. The cause for this is i want to iterate objects that i may not know the property names for using keys, but possible assign certain properties to a newly created object using that same name. I cannot use extend as i dont what all property names missing.

Comment: if something doesn't work, then show the actual or a [mcve] of the code that doesn't work. As the code you show should work as long as you have some variable named `something`, https://jsfiddle.net/vL1urjea/

Comment: Code looks like it should work to me.  `newPropertyName` is `"test"`.  You're using a variable to set a property on an initialized object.  I don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, if we log your code like this:

```
var obj = {};

var newPropertyName = 'Test';
var something = "something";

// normal assignment
obj.newProperty = something;

// as you said, we expect this to be true
console.log(obj["newProperty"] === something); // expect true



// We test:
obj[newPropertyName] = something

// and log, wth the expectation that this will equal the value of 
// something, which is "something"
console.log(obj.Test)
```

then we get a console log of:

```
true
"something"
```

which is what we expect.

You can play with this here: https://jsbin.com/vivayipevi/edit?js,console

Comment: What i tried that before posting and wasnt seeming to work, so i posted this as example to explain what i need to do.  I guess it is correct then, so thank you and feel like idiot for that one. Thanks agan

Comment: No worries, might want to check for syntax errors or something like that :) good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i was way over thinking it when posted. Was another error triggering it to not work correctly. I was writing a generic function to do a time converter on any property from kendo grid, so this helped em handle that. Thanks again.